# How to discard skipped messages for specific message types in a saga endpoint

Tags: masstransit, saga

I'm working on a project using a saga pattern with MassTransit and I have a scenario where I want to discard skipped messages, but only for specific types of messages. I know that MassTransit provides the `DiscardSkippedMessages` option, but it applies to all skipped messages.

Is there a way to configure MassTransit to discard skipped messages only for certain message types within a saga endpoint?

I've searched through the MassTransit documentation but I couldn't find a direct solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have known message types that are usually handled by the saga but for whatever reason are ending up in the *_skipped* queue, you should look at *ignoring* those events in invalid states.

```cs
During(SomeState, Ignore(SkippedEvent));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The provided solution will work for messages that are correctly correlated with a saga. In my example, I have multiple sagas that handle messages of the same type. If a message is correlated with one of them, it will be forwarded to the skipped queue on the other endpoint. That's why I would like to configure the skipping of forwarding to the skipped queue for such messages, especially when a message is not correlated with any saga instances.

Comment: There is an `OnMissingInstance` when defining an event that can be used as well, but without a complete example of what you're trying to do with code, I'm only guessing.

Comment: Great! `OnMissingInstance(e => e.Discard())` seems to be exactly what I needed. Thank you very much

Comment: I have just noticed that if a message reaching the consumer of the saga does not have the property on which correlation occurs (its value is null), then such message is sent to the skipped queue. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: `OnMissingInstance()` will let you configure the missing instance behavior for events.

Comment: Unfortunately when correlating property is null then `OnMissingInstance()` does not work. We've got message correlation configured like this: `.CorrelateBy(i => i.ProcessId, x => x.ProcessId)` and when `ProcessId` is null in an incomming message, then the message is sent to `_skipped` queue regardless of the `OnMissingInstance()` setting.